# Matlab variables show 'reference-like' behavior when copied and passed to a mex file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, matlab, mex

I have a mex file (compiled in VS2010, Matlab 2010b) which accepts a variable, and change it. For example, in the mex file it looks like:

```
double *fp = (double *)mxGetPr (prhs[0]);
*fp = someDoubleValue;
```

In order to compare the Matlab implementation and the mex implementation, I make a copy of the variable before calling the mex file:

```
var_mex = var;
mymex (var_mex);
```

To my surprise, both `var_mex` and `var` change (to the same value of course), as if I created a reference to `var` and not a copy of it.

Is this a known issue? How can I convince Matlab to copy the variable?

**EDIT**

Since I suspected that this issue is a result of Matlab optimizing its memory management, I did some "do nothing" calculation on `var` before calling the mex file, i.e

```
var=var+1;
var=var-1;
```

and indeed it solves the problem. I would still be glad to get some information (or other suggestions) on this, if someone encountered it as well.

Comment: It appears to be by design going by [this page](http://www.mit.edu/~pwb/matlab/). Perhaps you could modify the var_mex before passing it in such as multiplying it by 1. Or adding 1 then subtracting 1 in two discrete steps.

Comment: yes, that exactly what I tried (and it worked, see my edit).

Comment: Have you read the Matlab documentation on [Matlab's memory management](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brh72ex-2.html)? It explains this behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MATLAB, most variables are passed around *as if* they are being passed by value. The notable exception to this is that instances of classes that inherit from `handle` are explicitly passed by reference.

There's a [blog entry here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/) which goes into some detail about this.

So, when you execute

```
var_mex = var;
```

You end up with `var_mex` referring to the same data as `var`.

When you're writing to an `mxArray` inside a mex function, you have great power to break things because you're given the underlying address of the data. If you modify an element of the `prhs` array, you might inadvertently end up modifying other variables sharing the same data. So, don't do that. In fact, the [mex doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mexfunction.html) explicitly tells you not to do that.

The reason that the `var + 1` trick works is that by modifying the data, you're forcing MATLAB to make a copy of the data.

Comment: "So don't do that. In fact, the mex doc explicitly tells you not to do that" +1 :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason the mex mechanism doesn't prevent you from changing the input variables?

Comment: Well, the mex interface does specify that the prhs pointers are const. The only feasible way that the mex interface could guarantee that you didn't cause visible modifications to prhs would be if they were duplicated on the way in to the mex function - which would be very inefficient.

Comment: MATLAB trusts you to wear your big boy C pants while using mex files.

Comment: I would add a clarification, that Matlab does "lazy" copying. So as long as a variable doesn't get modified, any copies of it are in fact references to the original data. Once a variable is modified, then a copy gets made. Matlab's functions know when to make copies of things before modifying them, but your mex file doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

All variables in Matlab are passed by value.

Making any changes directly on rhs arguments in a Matlab mexfunction is not officially supported.
If you are converting a Matlab function of the form `A = func(A)`, then  you are "required" to make a copy of the passed array `A` inside the mexfunction itself.

Comment: In the MATLAB language itself, variables are passed *as if by value* using copy-on-write semantics. This explains why adding the addition/subtraction 'fixes' things - the value is modified, and therefore a copy must be made. Once you're in the world of MEX files - you're on your own, and can subvert MATLAB's standard memory management to some extent.

Comment: @Edric: Why don't you expand the comment into an answer?